# android volley POST integer

Tags: android, webservice, post

En el web service tengo el siguiente método

```
public int Post([FromBody]JObject value)
    {
        int count = 0;

        try
        {
            //Primero comprobamos que el usuario y el hash son correctos
            int idUser = Convert.ToInt32(value["idUser"]);

            string userHash = value["Hash"].ToString();

            UsuarioWS user = CL.Usuarios.GetUsuario(idUser, userHash.ToString());

            if (user.Usuario != 0 && user.Hash != "")
            {
                int diasAmostrar = Convert.ToInt32(value["diasMostrar"]);

                int filtro = Convert.ToInt32(value["filtro"]);

                EnumFiltroServicio enumFiltro = EnumFiltroServicio.NINGUNO;

                switch (filtro)
                {
                    case 1:
                        enumFiltro = EnumFiltroServicio.PENDIENTES;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        enumFiltro = EnumFiltroServicio.VENCIDOS;
                        break;
                    default:
                        enumFiltro = EnumFiltroServicio.NINGUNO;
                        break;
                }

                count = CL.Instalaciones.GetCountEquiposMantenimientos(enumFiltro, diasAmostrar);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ManagementError.Error(ex);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

y quiero recuperar ese count usando volley pasando los parámetros en android. ¿Qué tipo de request POST debo hacer (como JsonObjectRequest...) para recoger la respuesta como int?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Primero debes asegurar que en realidad retorna como respuesta el "int" que comentas, ya lo revisaste?

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias por tu respuesta. Al final lo recupero como un String.